# Unable to execute a function in react native using sqlite

Tags: react-native, sqlite

I am not sure why the onPress {deleteNote} function is not being called. When i try to output using console.log it also does not show any output in the terminal window.  Upon pressing running the deleteNote function, it is supposed to remove a row from the to-do list.  But whenever i click the delete button nothing happens.

```
        import { Entypo } from "@expo/vector-icons";
        import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
        import {
            FlatList, StyleSheet,
            Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Alert
        } from "react-native";
        import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
        
        import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";
        const db = SQLite.openDatabase("notes.db");
        
        export default function NotesScreen({ navigation, route }) {
         const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
        
         function refreshNotes() {
             db.transaction((tx) => {
                 tx.executeSql(
                     "SELECT * FROM notes",
                     null,
                     (txObj, { rows: { _array } }) => setNotes(_array),
                     (txObj, error) => console.log("Error ", error)
                 );
             });
         }
        
         useEffect(() => {
         db.transaction((tx) => {
             tx.executeSql(
                 `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
                 notes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, done INT);`
             );
         });
        }, []);
        
        
         useEffect(() => {
           navigation.setOptions({
             headerRight: () => (
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={addNote}>
                 <Entypo
                   name="new-message"
                   size={24}
                   color="black"
                   style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                 />
               </TouchableOpacity>
             ),
           });
         });
        
         useEffect(() => {
            if (route.params?.text) {
              db.transaction(
                  (tx) => {
                tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO notes (done, title) VALUES (0, ?)", [
                  route.params.text,
                ]);
              },
              null,
              refreshNotes
              );
            }
          }, [route.params?.text]);
        
          function deletNote() {
            console.log ('Test')
          db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
              "DELETE FROM notes WHERE id = ${id}",
            )
          })
          refreshNotes
        }
        
         function addNote() {
           navigation.navigate("Add Note");
         }
        
         function renderItem({ item }) {
           return (
             
             <View
               style={{
                 padding: 20,
                 paddingTop: 20,
                 paddingBottom: 20,
                 borderBottomColor: "#ccc",
                 borderBottomWidth: 1,
                 flexDirection: "row",
                 justifyContent: "space-between"
               }}
             >
               <Text style={{ textAlign: "left", fontSize: 16 }}>{item.title}</Text>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={deletNote}>
                <View style={styles.delete}>
                  <Icon name="delete" size={20} color="#3143e8" />
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
           );
         }
        
         return (
           <View style={styles.container}>
             <FlatList
               style={{ width: "100%", flexdirection: "row"}}
               data={notes}
               renderItem={renderItem}
             />
           </View>
         );
        }
        
        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
         container: {
           flex: 1,
           backgroundColor: "#ffc",
           alignItems: "center",
           justifyContent: "space-between",
         },
         delete: {
          flexDirection: "row",
        },
        });

`
```

Comment: Hey, you have a statement at the end of deletNote function, called 'refreshNotes', it should not be 'refreshNotes()'?

Comment: Hi Douglas.  Thanks.  It worked!